# How to convert C array to std::initializer_list?

Tags: c++, gcc, visual-c++

I know a pointer to an array and its size. What container can be created from it? I tried to do this:

```
std::initializer_list<int> foo(arr, arr + size);
```

It works for the MSVC, but not for the gcc

Comment: The `Initializer_list` constructor is really simple: `constexpr initializer_list() noexcept;`. If `std::initializer_list<int> foo(arr, arr + size);` works under Visual Studio, it's because they added extensions.

Comment: `initializer_list` is designed for use with braced lists of times, it's not a general container. You can use `vector` or `span` among other options

Comment: What is the end goal for this list? It may be easier to pass around the array and length until you need it. If not, I'd start with `std::vector` and probably ditch the array entirely.

Comment: Leads to a question: Why not use a `std::vector` in the first place? What's the array good for if you're just going to stuff it in a container later anyway?

Comment: An important addition - I do not want to copy memory. MSVC's initializer_list just provides an interface for iterating over an array.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`std::initializer_list`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list) is a reference-type designed just for supporting list-initialization, and only has the default-ctor, and implicitly copy-ctor. Any other ctor is an extension.

What you can do is initializing the target-container directly from an iterator-range, without involving any intermediate views.

The standard container to use unless you know better would be [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector). Or would using a simple view like [`std::span`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/span) be enough for you?

Comment: `std::span` is exactly what I'm looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

If you need an actual data owning container, then what you want is a [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).  This is going to cost you a copy and an allocation. If all you need is to act like a container, then what you want is the upcoming [`std::span`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/span) from C++20.  It takes a pointer and a size and wraps it in an interface that is like an array.

MSVS's use of

```
std::initializer_list<int> foo(arr, arr + size);
```

is not standard.  [Per the standard](https://eel.is/c++draft/support.initlist.cons) the only constructor for `std::initiliazer_list` is

```
constexpr initializer_list() noexcept;
```

Comment: Span is way overkill here. You can create any container from `arr, arr + size`.

Comment: @NicolBolas All of those will copy.  Span is "zero cost".

Comment: The OP asked, "What container can be created from it?" `span` is not a container. The `initializer_list` was just a means to an end.

Comment: @NicolBolas Goiod point.  It's listed under [\[containers\]](https://eel.is/c++draft/#containers) so that threw me.

Answer (score 4):

There are kind of two questions here, each with their own answer.

---

> How to convert C array to std::initializer_list?

You can't. It doesn't really make sense to. [`std::initializer_list`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list) is really only used to initialize (as its name implies) objects. It's basically is what is created from the `{}` notation like this:

```
myObject obj = {0,1,2,3,4};
```

Attempting to create an instance of an `std::initializer_list` isn't really useful in any other sense that I can think of, especially since C++14 [it's impossible to create at runtime](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list/initializer_list) anyway, since it has a `constexpr` constructor.

---

If you have some object `foo` that accepts an `std::initializer_list`, like this:

```
class foo {
    foo(std::initializer_list list) {
        //...
    }
};
```

And you are wondering how to create this object without an`std::initializer_list`, then the answer is to simply add another constructor:

```
class foo {
    // an actual array
    foo(type arr[size]) {
        //...
    }

    // as a pointer
    foo(type arr*, size_t size) {
        //...
    }
};
```

If you are using a third party library, or some other library you don't control, that does not have another constructor, then chances are it's not intended to be used this way. In that case, I would consult your documentation or vendor.

---

> What container can be created from it?

Any [sequence container](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container). Most of them have some sort of constructor that accepts pointers to an object (actually, it technically takes iterators, but pointers will work the same in this context) or an array. They are pretty much designed for easy conversion from C arrays. Which one you use will depend on your situation.

Also, [`std::span`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/span) (which is not listed as a "sequence container") has been mentioned as a possible container that can get created from a C array at low cost. Although, I can't vouch for them personally, as I'm not too familiar with the upcoming standard.

---

Final note: If MSVC allows this, then either a) you're possibly in C++11 (though I can't confirm if this was allowed in C++11 either, just that the constructor is not `constexpr` in C++) or b) it is a compiler bug in MSVC.

Comment: "And you are wondering how to create this object without an std::initializer_list, then the answer is to simply add another constructor:" - Can I do it in tensorflow internal classes?They do have only  std::initializer_list as input and they make - no other. Why ?? Why was it so hard to make a  std::initializer_list contructor from any container ?